# Why does .get() result in TypeError: posts.get is not a function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to console log a query of all the available documents within the Posts collection in firebase. Can someone explain why .get() is not a function when I'm literally using the same code from firebase docs?

```
const posts = collection(db, 'Posts');

async function getAllDocs() {
    const snapshot = await posts.get();
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing two versions of the Firebase API that are not compatible with each other.

Your first line uses the newer v9 modular API, while the like that is failing is trying to use the older v8 namespaced API. The two can't be mixed like that.

If you want to use the v9 modular API, the failing line should be:

```
const snapshot = getDocs(posts);
```

When doing this type of development I always keep the Firebase documentation handy, as it has side-by-side snippets of the two API versions. For example, this specific case is covered in the documentation on [getting all documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web-version-9_6).

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure what happened there. I copied the node.js code snippet from the documentation.